# Replacing "line number" in a regex

Tags: regex, notepad++

I am converting a CSV list of fields with description in C# code in order to describe a new class. This is to be used to map to CSV an Entity Framework entity with 130 fields.

I successfully captured the field name and descriptive name and replaced to property syntax

```
"?([^",\n]+)"?,"?([^",\n]+)"?,"?([^",\n]+)"?,"?([^",\n]+)"?
[CsvColumn\(Name="$2",FieldIndex=1\)][DisplayName\("$2"\)] public string $1 {get; set;}\n
```

This takes an attribute definition like (0 is a constant coming from DB)

```
paulaBean,"Brilliant","Paula Bean is Brilliant",0
```

And generates a property like

```
[CsvColumn(Name="Brilliant",FieldIndex = 1)]
[DisplayName("Brilliant")]
public string paulaBean {get; set;}
```

I use the LinqToCsv library and it uses an attribute ordering. I prefer that my attributes are encoded into CSV in the same order they appear in the class, which is the order they appear in the original CSV list

### The question IS

Using a regex, how can I replace `FieldIndex = 1` with the actual occurrence or line number or whatever incremental? I simply need to order fields from 1 to 130 and get a different incremental number for every property generated by my regex.

Comment: This is actually **not** a C# question as I do replacement with Notepad++

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not possible with notepad++

Download TextPad

Make sure the cursor is at the top of the file

Open Replace feature:

```
Find: FieldIndex = \d+
Replace by:  \i
```

Replace all

Answer (score 0):

It's possible, you just select the column using Shift-Alt-Down and use Column Editor in the Edit menu. See the tutorial here -- https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_4PQ1ZLxYk0 (not mine:)